# Making an HTTP POST request to Facebook Graph API in Node JS with default http API

Tags: node.js, http, post, facebook-graph-api

I need to post a picture on a Facebook page by doing a graph API call.
Executing this:

```
curl --request POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{pageId}/photos?url={imageUrl}&message={message}&access_token={pageAccessKey}"
```

It works wonderfully, without an itch. However, I can't seem to make this work on Node.

```
const http = require("follow-redirects").http;
const querystring = require("querystring");

const pageId = "pageId";
const pageAccessKey = "pageAccessKey";

function facebookPostImage(imageUrl, message) {

    const data = querystring.stringify({

        access_token: pageAccessKey,
        url: imageUrl,
        message: message
    });

    const options = {

        method: "POST",
        hostname: "graph.facebook.com",
        path: `/${pageId}/photos`,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length": data.length,
        }
    };

    const request = http.request(options, response => {

        console.log(`statusCode: ${response.statusCode}`);

        response.on("data", chunk => {
    
            process.stdout.write(chunk);
        });    
    });

    request.on("error", error => {

        console.error(error);
    });

    request.write(data);

    request.end();
}
```

Calling `facebookPostImage` only prints to the console "statusCode: 500".
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples of a Facebook Graph API call (or even examples of a generic urlencoded http request) through these http APIs, so I really can't understand what's wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: Why do you have a question mark at the end of the endpoint path?

Comment: @CBroe it's actually something I added out of desperation just to try if it would work. I'm going to edit the snippet of code.

Comment: You are likely not _only_ getting a 500 status code, the response body usually contains a human readable error message as well. So go check what that contains in this instance then.

Comment: @CBroe isn't the response.on("data") bit for that? Also on errors it should print it out something. What's bizarre is that if I encode the data in JSON (which I mistakenly did at some point) it actually gives me a human readable error ("A user access token is required to request this resource."), along with a different status code (400).

Comment: Surprised it even goes into that block of code, I thought an HTTP error like 500 should trigger the `request.on("error"` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not equivalent to the cURL call. The cURL line performs this HTTP request:

```
POST /{pageId}/photos?url={imageUrl}&message={message}&access_token={pageAccessKey} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
...some other headers...

--- END OF REQUEST ---
```

(note how there is no body!)

Your Node.js code does this instead:

```
POST /{pageId}/photos HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: <some integer>

url={imageUrl}&message={message}&access_token={pageAccessKey}
--- END OF REQUEST ---
```

`--- END OF REQUEST ---` has been added for legibility.

You need to actually pass the parameters as query string params and not as form body. This may seem counter-intuitive, because query params are most commonly used with GET requests.

Comment: This is actually what I did at first, but it didn't work so I tried doing what I showed in the snippet that I posted. Indeed, if I set options.path to `/${pageId}/photos?${data}` and I remove the headers and the call to request.write(), it keeps on returning a 500 status code with no error message. Is there something else I'm forgetting about?

Comment: @Gian try running `curl` with the `-v` flag and find out what headers it's sending, replicate that in Node.

Comment: @Robet Kawecki It basically looks identical to what you wrote except for user-agent: curl/7.74.0 and accept:  and for the fact that it's using HTTP/2

Comment: @Gian try HTTPS, not `http` - the API probably doesn't support unencrypted connections.

Comment: @Robet Kawecki I can't believe it, it was literally one character short from working. Thank you very much.